# Modulo Operation in Cassandra Query

Tags: cassandra, modulo, cql

I want to update a cassandra table based on the value of a cell. I want to use the modulo operator within the update query. 
Somehow like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycounter=(mycounter+90)%360 WHERE mykey="keyvalue";
```

How is this possible?
Or do I need to fetch the value, apply the modulo operation and write it back? 
Just adding something seems to possible as far the updated field has the datatype counter, but I don't know how to apply the modulo operation within the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's a good question.  I wasn't sure about this one, so I thought I'd test it out myself:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 192.168.1.69:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.0-rc5-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
aploetz@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE counterModTest (mykey text, mycounter counter, PRIMARY KEY(mykey));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter+1 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter+4 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM countermodtest ;

 mykey    | mycounter
----------+-----------
 keyvalue |         5

(1 rows)
```

So far, so good.  Table created, value initialized and incremented by 4.  Now for the tricky part:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter%4 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 46
  UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter%4 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
                                               ^
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter*4 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:45 no viable alternative at input '*' (UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=[mycounter]*...)">
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter/4 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 46
  UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter/4 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
                                               ^
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter^2 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 46
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE countermodtest SET mycounter=mycounter-1 WHERE mykey='keyvalue';
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM countermodtest ;

 mykey    | mycounter
----------+-----------
 keyvalue |         4

(1 rows)
```

I tried it out with +, -, *, /, ^ and %.  It looks like the only mathematical operators that worked are + and -.  Nice idea, but for now I think you're going to have to query that row by key, adjust the counter with % (or whatever operator) client-side, and then `UPDATE` it.  And since you cannot set a counter column to a specific value, you'll either have to store it as a `bigint` or (if it really needs to be a counter column) come up with some other tricky way to update it.

Comment: "or...come up with some other tricky way to update it." Yes, keeping in mind a distributed environment and eventual consistency.

Comment: Right.  Reading before writing isn't really a foolproof plan with Cassandra.